# how to appear data column-wise for different population set/generation set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have following data of 3 populations, (it can be 'n'). Each population contain 38 distinct records, I have all the data stored in row-wise, I want to display the data column wise for all the populations. Following is the data stored in temporary table:

```
pid s      carrier    sc    c   w
1   1      Ufone      331   20  3.289474
1   2      Ufone      332   24  3.947368
1   3      Ufone      333   93  15.29605
1   4      Ufone      334   38  6.25
1   5      Ufone      335   10  1.644737
1   6      Ufone      336   32  5.263158
1   7      Mobilink   300   43  7.072369
1   8      Mobilink   301   9   1.480263
1   9      Mobilink   302   10  1.644737
1   10     Mobilink   303   4   0.6578947
1   11     Mobilink   304   0   0
1   12     Mobilink   305   3   0.493421
1   13     Mobilink   306   6   0.9868421
1   14     Mobilink   307   13  2.138158
1   15     Mobilink   320   5   0.8223684
1   16     Mobilink   321   17  2.796053
1   17     Mobilink   322   11  1.809211
1   18     Mobilink   323   3   0.493421
1   19     Telenor    340   4   0.6578947
1   20     Telenor    341   14  2.302632
1   21     Telenor    342   7   1.151316
1   22     Telenor    343   5   0.8223684
1   23     Telenor    344   14  2.302632
1   24     Telenor    345   39  6.414474
1   25     Telenor    346   0   0
1   26     Telenor    347   0   0
1   27     Telenor    348   0   0
1   28     Telenor    349   1   0.1644737
1   29     Zong       310   8   1.315789
1   30     Zong       311   13  2.138158
1   31     Zong       312   25  4.111842
1   32     Zong       313   61  10.0329
1   33     Zong       314   17  2.796053
1   34     Zong       315   11  1.809211
1   35     Zong       316   23  3.782895
1   36     Zong       317   11  1.809211
1   37     Zong       318   5   0.8223684
1   38     Zong       319   9   1.480263
2   1      Ufone      331   19  3.869654
2   2      Ufone      332   19  3.869654
2   3      Ufone      333   71  14.46029
2   4      Ufone      334   35  7.12831
2   5      Ufone      335   8   1.629328
2   6      Ufone      336   19  3.869654
2   7      Mobilink   300   32  6.517312
2   8      Mobilink   301   14  2.851324
2   9      Mobilink   302   9   1.832994
2   10     Mobilink   303   3   0.610998
2   11     Mobilink   304   5   1.01833
2   12     Mobilink   305   2   0.407332
2   13     Mobilink   306   5   1.01833
2   14     Mobilink   307   1   0.203666
2   15     Mobilink   320   2   0.407332
2   16     Mobilink   321   16  3.258656
2   17     Mobilink   322   10  2.03666
2   18     Mobilink   323   3   0.610998
2   19     Telenor    340   3   0.610998
2   20     Telenor    341   7   1.425662
2   21     Telenor    342   4   0.8146639
2   22     Telenor    343   4   0.8146639
2   23     Telenor    344   10  2.03666
2   24     Telenor    345   31  6.313646
2   25     Telenor    346   3   0.610998
2   26     Telenor    347   1   0.203666
2   27     Telenor    348   1   0.203666
2   28     Telenor    349   0   0
2   29     Zong       310   14  2.851324
2   30     Zong       311   6   1.221996
2   31     Zong       312   23  4.684318
2   32     Zong       313   52  10.59063
2   33     Zong       314   16  3.258656
2   34     Zong       315   6   1.221996
2   35     Zong       316   15  3.05499
2   36     Zong       317   8   1.629328
2   37     Zong       318   1   0.203666
2   38     Zong       319   13  2.647658
3   1      Ufone      331   4   4.494382
3   2      Ufone      332   2   2.247191
3   3      Ufone      333   20  22.47191
3   4      Ufone      334   9   10.11236
3   5      Ufone      335   0   0
3   6      Ufone      336   3   3.370786
3   7      Mobilink   300   4   4.494382
3   8      Mobilink   301   6   6.741573
3   9      Mobilink   302   1   1.123595
3   10     Mobilink   303   0   0
3   11     Mobilink   304   1   1.123595
3   12     Mobilink   305   0   0
3   13     Mobilink   306   0   0
3   14     Mobilink   307   1   1.123595
3   15     Mobilink   320   0   0
3   16     Mobilink   321   4   4.494382
3   17     Mobilink   322   2   2.247191
3   18     Mobilink   323   1   1.123595
3   19     Telenor    340   2   2.247191
3   20     Telenor    341   1   1.123595
3   21     Telenor    342   0   0
3   22     Telenor    343   1   1.123595
3   23     Telenor    344   2   2.247191
3   24     Telenor    345   1   1.123595
3   25     Telenor    346   0   0
3   26     Telenor    347   0   0
3   27     Telenor    348   0   0
3   28     Telenor    349   1   1.123595
3   29     Zong       310   3   3.370786
3   30     Zong       311   4   4.494382
3   31     Zong       312   1   1.123595
3   32     Zong       313   9   10.11236
3   33     Zong       314   0   0
3   34     Zong       315   0   0
3   35     Zong       316   3   3.370786
3   36     Zong       317   1   1.123595
3   37     Zong       318   0   0
3   38     Zong       319   2   2.247191
```

And I want resulting record set as:

```
pid1_s  pid1_carrier    pid1_sc pid1_c  pid1_w  pid2_s  pid2_carrier       pid2_sc  pid2_c  pid2_w  pid3_s  pid3_carrier    pid3_sc pid3_c  pid3_w
1   Ufone   331 20  3.289474    1   Ufone   331 19  3.869654    1   Ufone   331 4   4.494382
2   Ufone   332 24  3.947368    2   Ufone   332 19  3.869654    2   Ufone   332 2   2.247191
3   Ufone   333 93  15.29605    3   Ufone   333 71  14.46029    3   Ufone   333 20  22.47191
4   Ufone   334 38  6.25    4   Ufone   334 35  7.12831 4   Ufone   334 9   10.11236
5   Ufone   335 10  1.644737    5   Ufone   335 8   1.629328    5   Ufone   335 0   0
6   Ufone   336 32  5.263158    6   Ufone   336 19  3.869654    6   Ufone   336 3   3.370786
7   Mobilink    300 43  7.072369    7   Mobilink    300 32  6.517312    7   Mobilink    300 4   4.494382
8   Mobilink    301 9   1.480263    8   Mobilink    301 14  2.851324    8   Mobilink    301 6   6.741573
9   Mobilink    302 10  1.644737    9   Mobilink    302 9   1.832994    9   Mobilink    302 1   1.123595
10  Mobilink    303 4   0.6578947   10  Mobilink    303 3   0.610998    10  Mobilink    303 0   0
11  Mobilink    304 0   0   11  Mobilink    304 5   1.01833 11  Mobilink    304 1   1.123595
12  Mobilink    305 3   0.493421    12  Mobilink    305 2   0.407332    12  Mobilink    305 0   0
13  Mobilink    306 6   0.9868421   13  Mobilink    306 5   1.01833 13  Mobilink    306 0   0
14  Mobilink    307 13  2.138158    14  Mobilink    307 1   0.203666    14  Mobilink    307 1   1.123595
15  Mobilink    320 5   0.8223684   15  Mobilink    320 2   0.407332    15  Mobilink    320 0   0
16  Mobilink    321 17  2.796053    16  Mobilink    321 16  3.258656    16  Mobilink    321 4   4.494382
17  Mobilink    322 11  1.809211    17  Mobilink    322 10  2.03666 17  Mobilink    322 2   2.247191
18  Mobilink    323 3   0.493421    18  Mobilink    323 3   0.610998    18  Mobilink    323 1   1.123595
19  Telenor 340 4   0.6578947   19  Telenor 340 3   0.610998    19  Telenor 340 2   2.247191
20  Telenor 341 14  2.302632    20  Telenor 341 7   1.425662    20  Telenor 341 1   1.123595
21  Telenor 342 7   1.151316    21  Telenor 342 4   0.8146639   21  Telenor 342 0   0
22  Telenor 343 5   0.8223684   22  Telenor 343 4   0.8146639   22  Telenor 343 1   1.123595
23  Telenor 344 14  2.302632    23  Telenor 344 10  2.03666 23  Telenor 344 2   2.247191
24  Telenor 345 39  6.414474    24  Telenor 345 31  6.313646    24  Telenor 345 1   1.123595
25  Telenor 346 0   0   25  Telenor 346 3   0.610998    25  Telenor 346 0   0
26  Telenor 347 0   0   26  Telenor 347 1   0.203666    26  Telenor 347 0   0
27  Telenor 348 0   0   27  Telenor 348 1   0.203666    27  Telenor 348 0   0
28  Telenor 349 1   0.1644737   28  Telenor 349 0   0   28  Telenor 349 1   1.123595
29  Zong    310 8   1.315789    29  Zong    310 14  2.851324    29  Zong    310 3   3.370786
30  Zong    311 13  2.138158    30  Zong    311 6   1.221996    30  Zong    311 4   4.494382
31  Zong    312 25  4.111842    31  Zong    312 23  4.684318    31  Zong    312 1   1.123595
32  Zong    313 61  10.0329 32  Zong    313 52  10.59063    32  Zong    313 9   10.11236
33  Zong    314 17  2.796053    33  Zong    314 16  3.258656    33  Zong    314 0   0
34  Zong    315 11  1.809211    34  Zong    315 6   1.221996    34  Zong    315 0   0
35  Zong    316 23  3.782895    35  Zong    316 15  3.05499 35  Zong    316 3   3.370786
36  Zong    317 11  1.809211    36  Zong    317 8   1.629328    36  Zong    317 1   1.123595
37  Zong    318 5   0.8223684   37  Zong    318 1   0.203666    37  Zong    318 0   0
38  Zong    319 9   1.480263    38  Zong    319 13  2.647658    38  Zong    319 2   2.247191
```

How to apply such join or cross tab?

Comment: Google "SQL pivot query."

Comment: Do you really need the database to prepare the data like that for you? If you have the possibility I would do it in the logic of your program.

Comment: @schlonzo ... Yes interested at database level to serve the processed data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ... Pivot Query tends to take some aggregate function as per my knowledge, I have nothing to aggregate, just want to display the data in columnar way.

Comment: You don't need to actually aggregate anything.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : Then how to get desired result using pivot? Can you assist?

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following query, which is along the way of what you want:

```
SELECT
    s,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pid = 1 THEN carrier END) AS pid1_carrier,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pid = 1 THEN sc END)      AS pid1_sc,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pid = 1 THEN c END)       AS pid1_c,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pid = 1 THEN w END)       AS pid1_w
    -- do the same for the other two pid values
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    s;
```

In this case, the pivot trick works using `MAX` because for each `s` value the `CASE` expression would only retain a non `NULL` value coming from a particular `pid` population.